# "You must have 20 reputation on The Stack Exchange Network to talk here."

Tags: support, chat, privileges

Whenever I try to enter chat it tells me, "You must have 20 reputation on The Stack Exchange Network to talk here". The same thing happens if I go into chat from some other Stack Exchange site.

I tried to look through The Stack Exchange Network and I found my profile on Stack Exchange Chat. If I interpret the information there correctly, I do have less than 20 reputation there. So I think I need to earn reputation there. How do you earn reputation on Stack Exchange Chat?

Comment: which chatroom are you trying to enter?

Comment: @robjohn http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics. However this is not the only chat room I can't talk in. I can't talk in any of the chat rooms.

Comment: There is something weird going on with your chat account. We are looking into it.

Comment: The best guess is that things got messed up in a recent merge. We are waiting for the SE team to look at it.

Comment: I had the same problems. What I did was I went to my chat account and clicked *change*, which is a link to the right of "Parent user". Here you type in "Mathematics", or some other site where you have at least 20 rep.

Comment: @user1 I went there, but I couldn't find the 'change' link that you were referring to.

Comment: @user1: that is the problem, there is no option to change the parent user. The community team is looking into this. Either the CT or a dev needs to tweak something.

Comment: @Alraxite: I am sorry this it taking a long time. We are still working on this.

Comment: @robjohn Oh, it's alright.

Comment: @Alraxite: one of the community team (Grace Note) has fixed up your account. You should be able to chat again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Evidently, something happened when an account was deleted; the chat account was still referencing a non-existent physics account. That has been fixed by the community team, and you should be able to chat again.

Comment: Thank you to you and Grace Note!